# Davydov's inequality and strongly mixing sequence.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, mixing

Let $\{X_i\}$ be an $\alpha$-mixing random process with coefficients $\alpha(k)$ satisfying $\alpha(k)\leq Ca^k$ for some positive constants $a<1$ and $C$. Given that for any $i\in \mathbb{N}$, $E\lvert X_i\rvert^q\leq C$ and $E\lvert X_i\rvert^r\leq C$ by some constant $C>0$, Davydov's inequality states that
$$\lvert \operatorname{Cov}( X_j,X_i)\rvert\leq C\alpha(\lvert i-j\rvert)^{1-1/q-1/r}.$$

Now, let the index $i$ be such that $\exists M>0:\lvert  i-l\rvert>M, \forall l\in\{i',j,j'\}$. Why the following inequality is valid, using Davydov's result:
$$\lvert \operatorname{Cov}( X_i,X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'})\rvert\leq C\alpha(M)^{1-1/q-1/r} ?$$
I do not know how to deal with the random variable $X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'}$ and its sigma-algebra generated.  If anyone knows about mixing properties, then please, give me advices!

*obs. If $\sigma(X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'})=\sigma(X_l:l\in\{i',j,j'\})$, then I can obtain the result. However, I don't think that a sequence of random variables generates the same sigma-algebra as its product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a question about your question that I hoped you might be able to help me with. How do we know that $E|X_{i'}X_jX_{j'}|^r<\infty$?

Comment: @Dasherman Sorry for the delay. Assume $E\lvert X_i \rvert^r\leq C$ bounded, for any $i$. Choose $r=4$ and $q=4/3$. Note that $1/r+1/q=1$. In addition, $E\lvert X_i\rvert^r\leq C$, and  by AM-GM inequality, $E\lvert X_{i'} X_j X_{j'} \rvert^q=E\lvert X_{i'}^q X_j^q X_{j'}^q \rvert\leq E[( X_{i'}^{3q}+ X_j^{3q} +X_{j'}^{3q} )/3]= (EX_{i'}^{r}+ EX_j^{r}+ EX_{j'}^{r})/3\leq C $, for some $C>0$. Indeed, the condition $r\geq 4$ is implicitly imposed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, in general, the equality $\sigma(X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'})=\sigma(X_l:l\in\{i',j,j'\})$ may not hold.  However, the inclusion 
$$
\sigma(X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'})\subset \sigma(X_l:l\in\{i',j,j'\})
$$
holds, because letting $f(x,y,z)=xyz$, the equality hold $\left\{X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'}\in B\right\}=
\left\{ \left(X_{i'},X_{j},X_{j'}\right)\in f^{-1}(B)\right\}$ and the latter is $\sigma(X_l:l\in\{i',j,j'\})$-measurable.

Comment: Thanks again Davide! Nice answer. As an observation, $f^{-1}$ is the inverse image, and not the  inverse function.

Comment: If I assume $\exists M>0:\exists l\in\{i',j,j'\}:\lvert  i-l\rvert>M, $, then
$\lvert Cov( X_i,X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'})\rvert\leq C\alpha(M)^{1-1/q-1/r}$ doesn't work in general. Do you agree with it? Surely, in this case,  $\lvert Cov( X_i,X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'})\rvert\leq C\alpha(\lvert i-l^*\rvert)^{1-1/q-1/r}$, where $l^*\in\{i',j,j'\}$ is the closest index to $i$.

Comment: Indeed, the later condition would not be sufficient for a good bound: take the $X_i$ centered i.i.d., $i'=i$ and $j=j'=i+M+1$: we get that $\operatorname{Cov}( X_i,X_{i'}X_{j}X_{j'})= E[X_1^2]^2$.

Comment: Davide. I'm dealing with this issue again, and posted a related question  here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668507/bounding-the-expectation-of-random-variables-product

Comment: Do you have any idea if it is possible to obatin a bound "near" $T^2$ as I mentioned there?