# Bounding the expectation of random variables' product.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, mixing

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of strongly mixing random variables, **not necessarily (strict) stationary**. Assume that $E\lvert X_i\rvert^4\leq C<\infty$ and that there is $0<a<1$ such that the mixing coefficient satisfies $\alpha(m)<Ca^{m}$. Here $C>0$ is a generic constant. Is there any chance (maybe, adding some assumptions) that 
$$\sum_{i,i',j,j'=1}^{T} E(X_i X_{i'} X_{j} X_{j'})\leq CT^2 v_T$$
for some $C>0$ constant and $v_T$ some slowly positive sequence converging to infinity?

This is far from trivial question. If someone know about mixing random processes, could you give me feedbacks?

For a while, I could only obtain a bound of order $O(T^3 v_T)$. This question relates to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562499/davydovs-inequality-and-strongly-mixing-sequence).

Comment: The beginning of chapter 2 in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00867106v2 is what you need, especially Theorem 2.1 I will write an answer tomorrow if nobody will do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. This gives me some insights, but I'm trying to find how to relate the result for fourth moment of sums with the  sum of moment of (four) products. I imagine that there is a convenient way to rewrite the indices of the sum. In addition, Rio showed in your link that for (essentially) bounded random variables, I can obtain the desired order $O(T^2)$. This condition is stronger than what I'm assuming above. With only bounded fourth moment, could I obtain a "good" bound like this?

Comment: Finally, can you readily see a way to obtain a bound of order $O(T^2)$ for the stationary case? In the initial version, I focused on the nonstationary case, but I have to allow the stationary case as well. I will be studying these Rio's results and find answers for the questions I just made. Feel free to comment them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 2.1 in [these notes by Emmanuel Rio](https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00867106v2/document) states the following: for a centered sequence $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 1}$, the following inequality holds.
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^4\right]\leqslant 3\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n \lvert \mathbb E\left[X_iX_j\right]\rvert\right)^2
+48 \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{0}^1\min\{\alpha^{-1}(u),n\}^3Q_k(u)^4du,
$$
where 
$$
Q_k(u)=\inf\{t>0\mid\mathbb P\{\lvert X_k\rvert>t\}\leqslant u\}
$$
and $\alpha^{-1}(u)=\operatorname{Card}\{n,\alpha(n)\geqslant u\}$.

After having expanded $\left(\sum_{t=1}^TX_t\right)^4$ one finds exactly $\sum_{i,i',j,j'=1}^{T} E(X_i X_{i'} X_{j} X_{j'})$. The term $\lvert \mathbb E\left[X_iX_j\right]\rvert$ can be control a the covariance inequality and $\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^T \lvert \mathbb E\left[X_iX_j\right]\rvert\right)^2$ is of order $T^2$.

If we furthermore assume that 
$\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\int_0^1\alpha^{-1}(u)^2Q_k(u)^4du$ is finite, then 
$\sum_{i,i',j,j'=1}^{T} E(X_i X_{i'} X_{j} X_{j'})$ is of order $T^2$. When the mixing rates are bounded by $a^n$ for $0<a<1$, $\alpha^{-1}(u)$  behave like $-c\ln u$ but finiteness of $\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\int_0^1\alpha^{-1}(u)^2Q_k(u)^4du$ is more restrictive than uniform boundedness of the moments of order $4$.

Comment: The quantile $Q_k$ is defined for $X_k^4$ or for $\lvert  X_k\rvert$? The second term in the sum of the RHS is obtained from both $48\sum_{k=1}^n M_{4,\alpha,n}(Q_k)$ or $48\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\alpha_{m+1}}^{\alpha_m}(m+1)^3Q_k^4(u)du$. Can you give me details how did you obtain the second term?

Comment: Do you believe that the definition of $M_{4,\alpha,n}(Q_k)$ in the refeered Theorem is right? It should've been defined without the summation, shouldn't it?

Comment: @CelineHarumi There were some inaccuracies in the previous version. I have edited.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Since I'm assuming geometric mixing rates, as you mentioned above, Rio says that it is sufficient to impose finiteness of expectation of $X^4(\log (1+X))^3$. It is probably stronger than I need. Now I will be studying the above result in the case where the indices $(i,i',j,j')\in J_1\times J_2\times J_3 \times J_4$ with $J_l\subseteq \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ and the cardinality $\#J_l=o(T)$ for each $l\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. In this way, I conjecture that I can obtain an even better upper bound.

Comment: $\# J_l=o(n)$...

Comment: Can you help with this proof verification? It's easier than the other questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684224/sub-triangle-array-of-strong-mixing-triangle-array-is-strong-mixing-proof-verif

Comment: I saw that the previous question in the link was imprecise. I updated it. Please, take a look if you have time.