# Inclusion of sigma-algebra generated by a sequence of random variables

Tags: measure-theory

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of random variables on $(\Omega,F,P)$ and $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. For any $1\leq i<k<\infty$, I want to evaluate if
$$\sigma(a_mx_m: i\leq m\leq k)\subseteq \sigma(x_m: i\leq m\leq k).$$

**My attempt**

The sigma-algebra generated by each element of $a_n$ is the trivial sigma-algebra. Then
$$\sigma(a_mx_m: i\leq m\leq k)=\sigma(\cup_{m=i}^k\sigma(a_mx_m))\subseteq \sigma(\cup_{m=i}^k(\sigma(x_m)\cup \{0,\Omega\}))=\sigma(\cup_{m=i}^k \sigma(x_m))$$
if $\sigma(a_mx_m)\subseteq \sigma(a_m,x_m)$ holds (which I'm not sure).

This implies the above result. *The inclusion was justified in the answer of this question [(here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562499/davydovs-inequality-and-strongly-mixing-sequence) (but I am still confused).

**Question** Do you have any alternative way to show this or to show the mentioned inclusion above?

Comment: One of your sigma algebras is $\sigma ((X_i,...,X_k))$, and the second one is $\sigma((a_iX_i,...,a_kX_k))$. Note that function $f:\mathbb R^{k-i+1} \to \mathbb R^{k-i+1}$ given by $f(x_i,...,x_k)=(a_ix_i,...,a_kx_k)$ is borel. So you're asking whether $\sigma(f(X_i,...,X_k)) \subset \sigma((X_i,...,X_k))$ holds or not. I can give you a general answer, for any borel $f$ it holds. Simply because (let $Y=(X_i,,,,X_k)$) you have $(f \circ Y)^{-1}[A] = Y^{-1}[f^{-1}[A]]$ and $f^{-1}[A]$ is borel set, too, all sets of type $(f \circ Y)^{-1}[A]$ are of type $Y^{-1}[B]$ for some borel set $B$

Comment: We can say more, if all of $a_i,...,a_k$ are not equal to $0$, then there exists inverse $g=f^{-1}$ (which is  just $g(x_i,...,x_k) = (\frac{x_i}{a_i},...,\frac{x_k}{a_k})$. In that case, you not only have the inclusion $\subset$, but also inclusion $\supset$, so your sigma algebras are equivalent in the case of all $a_i,...,a_k \neq 0$

Comment: @DominikKutek Very nice comment. Instead of focus on the inclusion of generated sigma-algebras by products  and generated sigma-algebras by collections, it is better to focuns on the composition of a Borel- measurable function with a random vector! Thanks. If you write your comment as an answer, I will vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general result holds:

Let $Y$ be a random variable with values in space $(E,\mathcal B(E))$, $f:E \to E$  be borel function. Then $\sigma(f(Y)) \subset \sigma(Y)$.

You should know that

$\sigma(Y) = \{ Y^{-1}[A] ; A \in \mathcal B(E) \}$

while

$\sigma(f(Y)) = \{ (f \circ Y)^{-1}[A] ; A \in \mathcal B(E) \} = \{ Y^{-1}[f^{-1}[A]] ; A \in \mathcal B(E)\}$

Since $f^{-1}[A]$ is a borel set, too ($f$ was a borel function), we know that every set $Y^{-1}[f^{-1}[A]]$ is also $Y^{-1}[B]$ for some borel $B$, so every $C \in \sigma(f(Y))$ is also in $\sigma(Y)$, so $\sigma(f(Y)) \subset \sigma(Y)$.

In your case $Y=(X_i,...,X_k)$ and $f(x_i,...,x_k) = (a_ix_i,...,a_kx_k)$ is a borel function (even continuous), so your result holds.

Note that when $f$ is invertible and $f^{-1}$ is borel, the other inclusion holds, too (since $Y= f^{-1}(f(Y))$, so $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(f^{-1}(f(Y))) \subset \sigma(f(Y)) \subset \sigma(Y)$).

By that we get : if every $a_i,...,a_k \neq 0$, then you have equality in those sigma fields (since the inverse then exists)