# Sigma algebra generated by product of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This question relates to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562499/davydovs-inequality-and-strongly-mixing-sequence).
Let $X,Y$ be two (real) random variables on $(\Omega,F)$. It was stated that
$$\sigma(XY)\subseteq \sigma(X,Y).$$

The argument used is as follows: let $f(x,y)=xy$ be a function and $B$ any Borel-measurable set. Then
$$\{XY\in B\}=\{(X,Y)\in f^{-1}(B)\}$$
and this latter is in $\sigma(X,Y)$ (or, is $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable).

Can someone clarify me this equality? Is this argument correct?

**My attempt**

$$XY(w)\in B \iff [f(X,Y)](w)\in B$$
By definition, $f^{-1}(B)=\{x:f(x)\in B \}$. So
$$[f(X,Y)](w)\in B\iff (X,Y)(w)\in f^{-1}(B)$$
The direction ($\implies$) of the last equivalence is not clear to me

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Any continuous function is Borel measurable so $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set for every Borel set $B$. So all you need is the fact that for any r.v. $Z$, the sigma algebra generated by $Z$ is given by $\sigma (Z)=\{Z^{-1} (B): B \, \text {is a Borel set}\} $. Finally $(X,Y) ^{-1} (E) \in \sigma (X,Y)$ for any Borel set $E$.

Comment: Isn't it $\sigma(Z)=\{Z^{-1}(B):B \text{ is a Borel set}\}$? I don't see that $Z(w)\in B \iff f(w)\in B$.

Comment: @CelineHarumi Sorry, that was  a typo.

Comment: But how to see that $\{XY\in B\}=\{(X,Y)\in f^{-1}(B)\}$?

Comment: Look at in this way: $\{\omega: (XY)(\omega) \in B\} = \{\omega: f(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \in B\} = \{\omega: (X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \in f^{-1}(B)\}$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong hum. The first equality made me treat the random variable $f(X,Y)$ as the composition $f\circ g$ where $g: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.  Using these definitions, I can accept the first equality.